# Ant task to compile stylus file to normal css file?

Tags: ant, stylus

I am trying to use [stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) in a project, that is using ANT build.

I need to compile the stylus file to normal css before packaging the war.

is there a way to do it?

Note : I am not using node.js, it is a simple java web application

Comment: Not familiar with stylus. The website gives info on how to install stylus but it's not clear how the "compile" works.... This looks suspiciously like a run-time rather than a static program compilation...

Comment: If you can execute an external program from your Ant script, just call `stylus path/to/style.styl`.

Comment: @LinusGThiel, Thanks, let me try that

Comment: stylus seems to be just a node package. so seems not possible without nodeJs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example how to use it:

```
    <property name="css.stylus" value="../folder/to/stylus/files"/>
    <property name="cmd.node" value="C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"/>
    <property name="cmd.stylus" value="C:\Program Files\nodejs\stylus.cmd"/>

    <target name="css_compile" description="compile l'ensemble des CSS avec stylus">
            <exec executable="${cmd.node}" />
            <exec dir="${css.stylus}" executable="${cmd.stylus}" >
                    <arg value="myCSS.styl"/>
                    <arg value="-c"/>
                    <arg value="-o"/>
                    <arg value="..\cssFolder"/>
            </exec>
    </target>
```

This example (I used) transform myCSS.styl in a obfuscate CSS to /cssFolder

- `nodevars.bat` is necessary for launching stylus.
- `stylus.cmd` is stylus itself, because the path not working in ant. To know where is it, (it's in nodejs), you can type "path" in terminal, on Windows.

That's all!